# How do I export the components of an app in Lotus Domino Designer?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a legacy Lotus Domino Web application - database with data, of course, but also JavaScript, Resources - including png and jpg images, subforms as HTML and CSS, etc.

I want to export the application itself - **not** the data, just the app structure - so I can reuse the images, HTML and CSS in other, more modern Web frameworks (e.g. Rails or NodeJS or PHP or Python or whatever) that consume HTML templates and CSS and JS as files.

How do I export the HTML, CSS, JS, png, jpg, etc. as is? I am happy to take the entire file structure as shown in Designer, just want to get the actual HTML/CSS/JS/images/etc. in there.

I tried using the "source control disk sync" option, but the files are saved in some strange Domino-specific XML format, with the underlying HTML/CSS/etc stored as hex. Not very helpful.

As an example, I might have in my app `Shared Elements\subforms\main.login.subform` (and many others) which look like:

```
<style>
#service-content {
    background-color: #fff;
}

label, input {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
    width: 300px;
}

#login-message, h1 {
    text-align: center;
}   
</style>
<div style="width: 450px; margin: 0 auto">
    <input type="hidden" value="/<Computed Value>/page?readform" name="RedirectTo" />

    <h1>Login</h1>
        <!-- lots of html here -->
</div>
<!--// NAVIGATION -->
```

I want to extract that (and the others like it).

EDIT:

As @AndrewB pointed out in the comments below, this is worth a better explanation.

The Domino app in question uses (mostly) static html and JS to retrieve data from agents via Ajax. So the UI (html/css/js) is very reusable with any backed, with some moderate amount of work.

But it only works if I can get the original static pages out. These statics are stored under `Resources\Files\` or `Shared Elements\subforms\`

EDIT 2:

When I turn off binary DXL export as per @sjcaged, I get output for the above raw HTML that looks like the following (this is just the end):

```
<font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30' color='#4200ff'/>"submit"</run>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30'/> </run>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30' color='purple'/>value</run>    
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30'/>=</run>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30' color='#4200ff'/>"Login"</run>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30'/> </run>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30' color='teal'/>&gt;&lt;/</run>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30' color='#3f8080'/>div</run>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30' color='teal'/>&gt;</run></par>
<par def='3'><run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30'/></run>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30' color='teal'/>&lt;/</run>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30' color='#3f8080'/>form</run>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30' color='teal'/>&gt;</run></par>
<par def='3'>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30' color='teal'/>&lt;/</run>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30' color='#3f8080'/>div</run>
<run><font name='Courier New' pitch='fixed' truetype='true' familyid='30' color='teal'/>&gt;
</run></par>
<par def='2'><run><font name='monospace'/>&lt;!--// NAVIGATION --&gt;</run></par></richtext>    
</body>
<item name='$$ScriptName' summary='false' sign='true'><text>main.nav</text></item></subform>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@deitch, you were almost there: you do want to enable source control.  How this works is it synchronizes the content of the database (either automatically or manually) with a standard filesystem directory.  See the help topic "Setting up the Source Control enablement feature" for more information.

To make it really work, though, requires changing a preference.  In Designer, first go to File | Preferences | Designer | Source Control.  Make sure that "use binary DXL" is not set.  See the help topic "Selecting the way to represent design elements on disk" for more information on the difference -- basically, using regular DXL separates the design element data [i.e. the code] from the DXL-formatted metadata wrapping that design element has in the database, where binary DXL puts them both into a binary blob and prevents external applications from being able to edit them.  There are other options here as well, see the help topic "Setting up Source Control enablement feature preferences" for more information.

After this is done, then (still in Designer) right-click the project, select "Team Development", and then 'Set up source control for this application'.  It may or may not show a splash screen and have you select Next, but eventually it will present a dialog box asking you to type the name of the on-disk project.  Make sure that the second line points to a directory which does not yet exist (by default, with the "use default location" checkbox selected, it will point to the Notes data directory and append to that whatever is entered as the name for the on-disk project as a new directory name).  When you select Finish, it will export the Eclipse virtual filesystem within the NSF to the filesystem, using that directory as the root.

(Not all Perspectives show the "Team Development" entry.  Notably, the Java Perspective doesn't.  The Domino Designer Perspective, however, does.  To change Perspective, select Window | Open Perspective and select the Perspective to use.)

Once this is done, you can use external tools to add the directory to source control [which is *always* a good idea]; as long as "use binary DXL" is unselected, you can also use external tools to manipulate the code and data considered to be part of the application.

Comment: Excellent! I will try it in the next few hours and report back.

Comment: Yes and no. I managed to try your suggestion... but only then realized that the devs had changed the code, and all of the static resources went missing. So it had nothing to export. They are supposedly fixing it overnight, so I will try again later on Friday. :-)

Comment: Well, it exported to html, and it contains everything, but it adds on hundreds of other styles and tags. Oh well.

Comment: Did it add on the styles and tags, or did the developers "fix" it with data that had the styles and tags?  I've never had Domino add anything to a resource that I didn't put there.

Comment: I don't really understand. To me, it looks like Domino added the styles and tags. I will update the question (too big for a comment).

Comment: That... looks like a presentation of the source code for the pages, rather than the source code itself.  Rather like github's view of a file in the repository, instead of the checkout of the file itself.  This looks like the designers destroyed the original code, and only had a presentation to import.  However, I'll check and see with some HTML in my installation.

Comment: Thanks @sjcaged. I am a bit lost here... :-)

Comment: I just checked with Domino 9.0.1.  Domino does not add the extra markup that you are seeing.  It looks like your developers didn't save the right version of the HTML.  (They probably copy-pasted it from a presentation via a ViewVCS or such.  What they need to do is paste it to Notepad, then copy from Notepad to paste it to the Eclipse HTML editor -- or instead of using Elipse HTML editor, use Eclipse Text Editor instead.)

Comment: I am actually using 8.5.1, but idea is the same. I think you are saying we would need to go to each file and change it? Might be easier to just do it from the browser. Well, your answer is great, the problem was how we did it here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: There is no way to do this.

The webcode shown in the browser is generated dynamically by the domino http- task from forms, views, pages, subforms, script- libraries, formulas, etc.

There is no simple html- representation anywhere in the database.

To get what you want you would need a leacher, that grabs and downloads the generated source as a browser would do. But as a lot of functionality is server- side (field validations, agents, sending mail, whatever...), you will not get anything sufficient from that approach.

Of course you could manually export the image- ressources, the css- files and probably JavaScript- Libaries (if there are any), but that will not get you any step further to what you want to achieve.

If you want to "migrate" the nsf to another platform, then you will have to rewrite the whole stuff...

Comment: Well, sort of. I am actually OK with the "raw" templates, the subforms that contain html and Domino references. But is there no way to just dump it all?

Comment: You could export the design as DXL, I suppose. But I am not sure how much that would help you, since most of the HTML code you see is created dynamically by the server.
Why do you even want to migrate? You can do a lot of things in Domino just by linking in Bootstrap and jQuery, and adding some CSS.

Comment: Unless the developer did not use "passthrough html" there will be nothing useful in the export. yes you could write an xslt to transform the xml- output to valid html, but again the complete functionality would be lost and you would simply get a dumb html page... And the html will be "ugly" as Domino still uses tables for formatting, what is not state of the art in modern web development...

Comment: Disagree with Torsten above, you can use whatever you like for formatting web page layout. Very few Lotus Domino developers use the old domino generated content, because especially with R8 and above you can generate code to web 2.0 standards fairly easily. As to the question, the business case would be very weak to recreate an entire website in a different language, just because you didn't want to work with the existing platform because you would have to start from scratch.

Comment: @AndrewB, you are making a good point. I didn't describe my problem well enough. I will edit my original question above.

Comment: @TorstenLink, do you mean that I can use an export (is that the sync to disk for version control, or is it the DXL export?) and pass it through an xslt to extract the original html/css/etc.? How could I do that? As I described in my latest edit to the question, I know I am missing the tables and linking, but I am willing to accept it to get the original html/css/js out.

Comment: I talked about dxl export... But "how" to write the xslt: this is a complete own topic and I personally do not know enough about xslt to answer your question. I just know: the work will be massive, and if you don't have lets say hundreds of templates to migrate it will be way faster to just copy the content of the forms / subforms (as it seems to be pass through html as you described it) using domino designer. I don't get the point at all: if you want to enhance this website then learn how to do it natively in Domino, if you want to migrate it: start from scratch...